# Class library loses references (dlls) when being used

Tags: c#, dll, reference, assemblies, class-library

Sorry for the title. I don't know how to describe this problem shortly.
My problem is that I have a `class-library` which has `references to other (third party) DLLs`.
I need to use this class-library in another project, so I obviously added the .dll of my class-library to my main-project.

When I start my main-project, there's alway an error which says, that a reference (dll) in my class-library cannot be found.

If I add the whole class-library as a project to my projectmap in visual studio and then reference the whole project, this error doesn't occur.

I really don't want to add the whole class-library as a project to every "host"-project I make.

Has anyone an idea why this error occurs when the .dll of the class-library is added, but not when the whole project of the class-library is added as reference?

There must be a solution to get this working even if I don't add the whole library-project as reference. Otherwise it wouldn't make any sense to make a class library, right?

**By the way**: My class-library contains third-party dlls and the local copy property of the third-party dll is set to true.

Thanks in advance!

**Edit**:
My goal is to really make the class-library portable, even though it contains third-party libraries. I want to give only the .dll to another pc and use it without adding the whole class-library project every time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is because you're not copying the dll's on the second project, you added a reference to your dll so it get's copied, but not the dll's referenced by your dll, so there are missing libraries.

Or you redistribute the dependencys with your dll or you can embedd the dll's inside your dll as resources and then intercept the assembly load and provide it through a resource: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/microsoft_press/archive/2010/02/03/jeffrey-richter-excerpt-2-from-clr-via-c-third-edition.aspx

EDIT: IN order to do it inside a dll you need to use an static class and call an static initializer BEFORE using any of the classes which are dependant on other libraries.

Here is an example setup:

-A library called LibraryB which supplies a simple class like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace LibraryB
{
    public class ReferencedClass
    {
        public int GetIt()
        {

            return 5;

        }
    }
}
```

-A library called LibraryA which references LibraryB and supplies two classes, the initializer and the real class:

**Initializer**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace LibraryA
{
    public static class Initializer
    {
        public static void Init()
        {
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += (sender, args) =>
            {

                if (!args.Name.StartsWith("LibraryB"))
                    return null;

                return Assembly.Load(LibraryA.Properties.Resources.LibraryB);

            }; 
        }
    }
}
```

**Class**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace LibraryA
{
    public class RealClass
    {
        public int DoIt()
        {

            LibraryB.ReferencedClass cl = new LibraryB.ReferencedClass();
            return cl.GetIt();

        }
    }
}
```

The LibraryA also has the LibraryB.dll compiled library embedded as a resource.

-A project called Test which only references LibraryA:

```
using LibraryA;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Initializer.Init();
            RealClass c = new RealClass();
            Console.WriteLine("From LibraryA: " + c.DoIt());
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

If you set-up everithing right and you execute it it will work, remember that if you are doing through visual studio, vs will copy the dll's so to do a real test after compiling all copy the exe and LibraryA and execute, it will work without LibraryB and LibraryB is being used from LibraryA.

Comment: He mentions that this works with executables (.exe). Does this also work with .dll's? I've never done this before nor heard anything about it. Thanks btw. this seems to be the right start to solve this problem.

Comment: It should, but I'm not 100% secure, best way is to test

Comment: I do, but it seems that there is already a problem. I can't call this while the "program" is initializing because there isn't even a start class (main) nor a constructor.

Comment: That should not be a problem, create an static class with an static function called "Init()", in that function hook the event. The user who wants to use your dll should first call that function and after that the libraries should be available. Let me check if that works and if it does I will expand the answer

Comment: It works, gimme 5 minutes and I will write an example.

Comment: Woah, it was a bit longer than 5 minutes :D

Comment: Wow, nice! Unfortunately, I can't access the properties with Namespace.Properties or anyhow else.

Comment: Did you added the resource from the Resources tab on the properties of the library project?

Comment: If you need I can pass you a solution with the three projects

Comment: You were right. I forgot to add the Resources.resx. I've never did that before either. I can't believe that this works! Thank you very much, you made my day! :D

Comment: Glad to help ;D Remember to instruct your users to call the init before doing nothing or an exception will rise.